# ActiveControl move from listview to textbox by using keys up C#

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I want to move ActiveControl from listview to textbox by using keys Up. but I get the problem when pressing the keys up. The first item in the listview can not be selected . if the item is selected in the second row and pressing the keys up , the focus will be on the textbox directly without passing through the first row.
i use this code:

```
    private void listView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
        {
            if (listView1.SelectedItems[0].Selected)
            {
                this.ActiveControl = textBox1;
            }
        }
```

anyone have an idea of the above problems ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code changes focus to textBox1 when the first selected item is selected.  Something that'll be true unless there's no selected items.

This is what you want to do:

```
private void listView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
    {
        if (listView1.Items[0].Selected)
        {
            this.ActiveControl = textBox1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Underdog Or you can use `KeyUp` event with your code.